# potential memory leak encode url

Tags: objective-c, ios

Why am I getting memory leaking while analyzing using XCode?

```
NSString *email = [defaults objectForKey:@"email"];
NSString *encodeEmail = (__bridge NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)email, NULL, CFSTR(":/?#[]@!$ &'()*+,;=\"<>%{}|\\^~`"), CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding));


NSString *urlp1=@"/xyz/xx/";
NSString *fullUrl=[urlp1 stringByAppendingString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/following", encodeEmail]];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [transitioning to ARC release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226)

> __bridge transfers a pointer between Objective-C and Core Foundation with no transfer of ownership.

It means encodeEmail doesn't have the ownership of the allocated memory, and so it won't be released by ARC.

I think you should use `__bridge_transfer`

> __bridge_transfer or CFBridgingRelease moves a non-Objective-C pointer to Objective-C and also transfers ownership to ARC. ARC is responsible
>   for relinquishing ownership of the object.

```
NSString *encodeEmail = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)email, NULL, CFSTR(":/?#[]@!$ &'()*+,;=\"<>%{}|\\^~`"), CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding));
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` which you have to release since you own it(Check the 'create' in the name)

You can try it as,

```
CFStringRef stringRef = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)email, NULL, CFSTR(":/?#[]@!$ &'()*+,;=\"<>%{}|\\^~`"), CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding));
encodeEmail = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",(NSString *)stringRef];
CFRelease(stringRef);
```

**Update:**
If you are using ARC, you can also use `__bridge_transfer` for transferring ownership from created `CFObjects` to `NSObjects`. You just have to use it as `NSString *encodeEmail = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)...`

Comment: Kicking it old school with the `CFRelease()`, nice.

Comment: Ya this is one option.. but since op is trying to use ARC, better keep it that way..

Comment: @Krishnabhadra, Yes, that is true. That is also an option.

Answer (score 1):

Because you will leak an object. To be specific the the `CFString` returned by the method `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` that method, which includes the keyword "create", returns a retained item. You must either manually release it, or tell ARC to handle it for you using:

```
NSString *encodeEmail = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)email, NULL, CFSTR(":/?#[]@!$ &'()*+,;=\"<>%{}|\\^~`"), CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding));
```

Note the `__bridge_transfer` that lets ARC handle the memory management for you, and it will eliminate your warning.